# openssl gives error while shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to solve some question. However my codes returns error..

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function decrypt {
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $hash | sed 's/988sn1/83unasa/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/4d298d/9999/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/3i8dqos82/873h4d/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/4n9Ls/20X/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/912oijs01/i7gg/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/k32jx0aa/n391s/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/nI72n/YzF1/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/82ns71n/2d49/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/JGcms1a/zIm12/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/MS9/4SIs/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/Ymxj00Ims/Uso18/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/sSi8Lm/Mit/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/9su2n/43n92ka/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/ggf3iunds/dn3i8/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/uBz/TT0K/g')

    flag=$(echo $MzSaas7k | base64 -d | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:$salt)
}


var="9M"
salt=""
hash="VTJGc2RHVmtYMTl2ZnYyNTdUeERVRnBtQWVGNmFWWVUySG1wTXNmRi9rQT0K"


for i in {1..28}
do
var=$(echo "$var" | base64)
done

salt="$var"

if [[ ! -z "$salt" ]]
then
    decrypt
    echo $flag
else
    exit 1
fi
```

but the output is that:

```
enc: Use -help for summary.
```

Could you help please?

I'm trying to solve the flag by encoding $var for 28 times and then use the function by using encoded string as my salt.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to get some hints.

Comment: If the suggestions from https://shellcheck.net don't solve your problem, update your code with the "corrections" listed by shellcheck. Good luck.

Comment: Are you certain the inner command `echo $MzSaas7k | base64 -d | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:$salt` is working when you replace varriables with hard-coded values? Fix that first. Also use `"dbl-quotes"` to surround those `"$variables"`. Good luck.